# Templates directory outside Django root

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a templates directory /var/opt/backoffice/templates and inside there is a template called foo.html. The directory is outside the Django root directory, which is /opt/backoffice.

I am trying to get Django to access the foo.html template in /var/opt/backoffice/templates using the get_templates('foo.html') command, but no matter what I try I get the error: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: foo.html

My settings.py for templates is:

```
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
           
            'DIRS': [
            'var/opt/backoffice/templates'
            ],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

My question is , how can I configure Django so that I can access  the template in /var/opt/backoffice/templates using get_templates('foo.html')?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a slash before `var`, that makes it a subdirectory rather than a root level dir:

```py
'DIRS': [
    '/var/opt/backoffice/templates'
],
```

I did not check with `/var` but it did work for me in another folder of my home directory outside of the Django project

Comment: Edoardo, you are officially my hero! Have a great weekend my friend!

Comment: I cannot believe that I made such a stupid mistake.

Comment: It happens :P Glad I could help :)